# Why do Speedtest Websites for Internet say that my connection is fast alltought its completely miserable? And how do i actually measure it?

Tags: download, speedtest.net

[image: Speedtest caught in proevidence]

Attached is a picture of a screenshot of a speedtest Website saying that my download speed is 3,68Mbps while im struggling to download a Pdf File with 119KBps.
Why dont those numbers match?
Also the download speed before I started testing was even lower at 39KBps.
Why do speedtest websites lie like this and how can i figure out what my actual internet speed is?

Comment: This seems to be more of an ISP/router issue rather than a speedtest.net issue.

Comment: 3.6Mbps is only about twice 119KBps. Test servers tend to have less competing traffic and are optimized to not be the bottleneck, caching the testload in ram on a dedicated box for example. Real-world file servers have more to do and won't be as fast. With that high ping time, it's also a factor of how big of chunks the file server sends and re-sends, and how long it has to wait for the acknowledgment from the client.

Answer (score -1):

The download speed is determined by two factors: your download speed and the upload speed from the source. The speed you experience is limited by the slower of the two. To troubleshoot and confirm any issues, you can compare performance by downloading a file from different sources.